# Queries regarding Workflow history list

Tags: designer-workflow, workflow-history

I have a list that has a workflow running on it and all its relevant information is stored in the Workflow History list. Now in SharePoint designer, I'm changing the default list to another history list and saving it. The workflow is scheduled to run when items are created / modified.

When I change something in the document and publishing it, the run does run as expected. However, I'm still seeing the old history list when I open the Workflow status for the modified document.

Is there a way to remove all the previous history list information?

Answer (score 0):

If you only saved the workflow in SPD then your change won't automatically be reflected. You need to republish your workflow.

Comment: Hi Erik, thank you for the reply. I noticed this issue even after republishing the workflow

Comment: Have you tried removing all the versions of your workflow from the list and then republishing it once more?